# Error in installing json 1.8.3 with ruby 2.4.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ubuntu

I am trying to run an open source web app on my local machine(Ubuntu 15.10). When I run `bundle` command I'm getting this

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/yesh/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/home/yesh/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170310-4319-tlc92v.rb
extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/home/yesh/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/home/yesh/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                         ^
generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
each function it appears in
generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                         ^
generator.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-tautological-compare’
Makefile:241: recipe for target 'generator.o' failed
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/yesh/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/home/yesh/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I tried `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` but again got the same error message as above. Please help in resolving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem as:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

and if above command didn't solve your system, you can try to install this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

You can refer at [json-1.8.3 Gem::Ext::BuildError](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253)

Because your ruby version is `2.4.0`.The ruby version is not compatible with `json 1.8.3`. You can try add this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'
```

Comment: I had tried these two but did not work

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesha i updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesha if my answer helped you to solve your problem, please mark it. thank you.

Comment: It does work great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Ruby version differs from Project's version of Ruby. JSON only supports `Integer` unification in Ruby from v. 2.0.0. and up - maybe some of the listed gems depend on `json (~> 1.8)`. Either comment out this gem in `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` or downgrade Ruby. [Read more about this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27450).

Comment: Commenting that line in Gemfile did not work. Maybe I will have to downgrade Ruby. :/